# VPNAgent high bandwidth usage

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, bandwidth

In my student residence, I need to connect to the internet through the university VPN, for which I use Cisco AnyConnect (as recommended by my university) on my Windows 10 desktop. The data limit per 30 days in my residence is 25GB. I did not think this relatively low data limit would be any problem, but noticed that after the first day I had already used 20% of the total allowed volume.

Using GlassWire, I found out that none of my programs are using insane amounts of data, except for *VPN Agent Service* and *Host process for Windows*. In less than an hour, those two programs combined downloaded over 2.8 GB.

Are those two programs essential for maintaining the VPN connection? If not, how can I delete them? If they are, how can I reduce their bandwidth usage to normal levels? At this rate I will have reached my data limit by day 5 and have no internet for the remaining 25.

Not knowing if it actually helps or not, I disabled *Captive Portal Detection* in the AnyConnect options. Since then I have not seen spikes as big as the previous ones in my bandwidth usage, but the usage still is fairly high.

Comment: I'd be wondering if the Uni is scanning your system and this is what the huge data is. Then again it could be anything :/

Comment: As you are following the University recommendations you should speak to their IT support.